# JavaFX: Custom setter name for FXML attribute?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have the following class that uses fluent setters in order to allow concatenation:

```java
/**
 * Data that affects the way an animation is played.
 */
public class AnimationSettings {

    private Duration duration = Duration.seconds(1);
    private Curve curve = Curve.LINEAR;

    /**
     * @param duration duration of the animation to set
     * @return this for concatenation
     */
    public AnimationSettings withDuration(Duration duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return duration of the animation
     */
    public Duration getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    /**
     * @param curve curve of the animation to set
     * @return this for concatenation
     */
    public AnimationSettings withCurve(Curve curve) {
        this.curve = curve;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return curve of the animation
     */
    public Curve getCurve() {
        return curve;
    }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is creating a new instance and set those values from an FXML file, like this:

```xml
<AnimatedNode>
    <settings>
        <AnimationSettings duration="900ms" curve="LINEAR"/>
    </settings>
</AnimatedNode>
```

However, an error is given as the attributes `duration` and `curve` can't be found.
After some investigation, I realized an FXML attribute should be linked to both a getter and setter, strictly named `getX` and `setX`, so my `withX` is not seen as a setter and the attribute cannot be set.

I was wondering if there is some annotation I am not aware of that tells JavaFX that a method should be treated as a setter, or some other way, as I think renaming those methods to `setX` would lose the 'fluent' feel.

Comment: After a bit more thought, you can probably do this with a `Builder`, though it's likely more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: "Classes that don't conform to Bean conventions can also be constructed in FXML, using an object called a "builder"." -> read the [fxml doc section on instance creation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#instance_declaration_elements) to understand what this means and how to do it.  You need to provide a custom [JavaFXBuilderFactory](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/JavaFXBuilderFactory.html) to the FXML loader constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made this work with a custom Builder. It's probably more effort than it is worth. I would recommend just implementing both `withCurve()` and `setCurve()` in your `AnimationSettings` class.

However, for demo purposes I added

```
package org.jamesd.examples.buildertest;

public enum Curve {
    LINEAR
}
```

Left `AnimationSettings` as-is:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.buildertest;

public class AnimationSettings {

    private Duration duration = Duration.seconds(1);
    private Curve curve = Curve.LINEAR;

    /**
     * @param duration duration of the animation to set
     * @return this for concatenation
     */
    public AnimationSettings withDuration(Duration duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return duration of the animation
     */
    public Duration getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    /**
     * @param curve curve of the animation to set
     * @return this for concatenation
     */
    public AnimationSettings withCurve(Curve curve) {
        this.curve = curve;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return curve of the animation
     */
    public Curve getCurve() {
        return curve;
    }
}
```

Then I created a builder for `AnimationSettings`. This is based on the [current implementation of `JavaFXFontBuilder`](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/70953643a9dc05c76924fc4c602ee39038d71295/modules/javafx.fxml/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/fxml/builder/JavaFXFontBuilder.java). This implementation makes it a `Map<String, Object>` implementation, with the `put(...)` method accepting the name of a property and its value. You can also implement this using Java Bean style `setCurve(...)` and `setDuration(...)` methods.

```
package org.jamesd.examples.buildertest;

import javafx.util.Builder;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.Set;

public class AnimationSettingsBuilder extends AbstractMap<String, Object> implements Builder<AnimationSettings> {

    private Duration duration = Duration.seconds(1);

    private Curve curve = Curve.LINEAR;

    @Override
    public AnimationSettings build() {
        return new AnimationSettings()
                .withCurve(curve)
                .withDuration(duration);
    }

    @Override
    public Object put(String key, Object value) {
        if ("duration".equals(key)) {
            // can parse units here if you want more flexibility, but for simplicity:
            duration = Duration.seconds(Double.parseDouble((String)value));
        } else if ("curve".equals(key)) {
            curve = Curve.valueOf((String)value);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return false; // False in this context means that the property is NOT read only
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(Object key) {
        return null; // In certain cases, get is also required to return null for read-write "properties"
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<String, Object>> entrySet() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

And then finally a builder factory. The builder factory has to implement the `getBuilder(...)` method. This just wraps a default implementation, returns the builder defined above to build `AnimationSettings` instances, and delegates to the default builder factory for other classes.

```
package org.jamesd.examples.buildertest;

import javafx.fxml.JavaFXBuilderFactory;
import javafx.util.Builder;
import javafx.util.BuilderFactory;

public class AnimationSettingsBuilderFactory implements BuilderFactory {

    private final BuilderFactory defaultBuilderFactory = new JavaFXBuilderFactory();
    @Override
    public Builder<?> getBuilder(Class<?> type) {
        if (type == AnimationSettings.class) {
            return new AnimationSettingsBuilder();
        }
        return defaultBuilderFactory.getBuilder(type);
    }
}
```

For simple testing, here is `Test.fxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import org.jamesd.examples.buildertest.AnimationSettings?>
<AnimationSettings xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
                   xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
                   duration="2.0" curve="LINEAR">

</AnimationSettings>
```

and `Test.java`:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.buildertest;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Test.class.getResource("Test.fxml"));
        loader.setBuilderFactory(new AnimationSettingsBuilderFactory());
        AnimationSettings settings = loader.load();
        System.out.println("Duration: "+settings.getDuration());
        System.out.println("Curve: "+settings.getCurve());
    }
}
```

Comment: A lot of effort was put here, thank you very much! I don't think adding all this code is worth it (it would also be hard to maintain) so I'll probably just add `setX` while keeping `withX` methods as you suggested.

Comment: @GiorgioG JavaFX used to have an alternate fluent builder API for most components, including an [animation builders](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/package-summary.html) but they were [deprecated and removed](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8092861?subTaskView=unresolved) for similar maintenance concerns as you state.

Comment: @GiorgioG. the code for all of the builders was open-sourced (you can find it in the [Gluon repository](https://github.com/gluonhq/8u-dev-rt/tree/master/modules/builders/src/main/java/javafx/animation)), though it is no longer maintained.  You can see many examples of builder classes there, though they are designed to work with the core JavaFX classes and not for your custom classes.  For your purposes, they would just serve as examples if you chose to create JavaFX-type builders (which it doesn't seem you will do in the end).